# Не работает деление в LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

Вот такой миксин:

```
.grid(@columns, @i: 1) when (@i <= @columns) {
.col-@{i} {
    max-width: percentage(@i / @columns);
    padding: 0 @15px;
    flex: 1;
}

.grid(@columns, @i + 1);
}

.grid(@columns);
```

Вот такая ошибка: Error evaluating function `percentage`: argument must be a number 
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте заключить в скобки деление `percentage((@i / @columns))`

Comment: @InDevX спасибо большое. Помогло